# Why isn't my while-loop starting after the std::thread is started?

Tags: c++, sfml

i've started doing a project with networking. But after setting up a the std::thread, the while(true)-loop wont start.

The first thing i have done is setting up the std::thread which is listening for new clients. In the function which the thread is using is a while(true)-loop, which perfectly works. In in the main thread after initializing the serverListener std::thread, is again a while(true)-loop which tries to recieve data, but this loop wont start, except when I put a std::cout in the while-loop before the for-loop, but this spams my console.

Variables and inclusions:

```cpp
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <thread>

#define PORT 1337

unsigned int clientCounter = 0;

sf::TcpSocket clients[5];
sf::Packet packet;
```

The function which the std::thread is using:

```cpp
void serverListener() {

    sf::TcpListener listener;
    listener.listen(PORT);

    while (true) {
        if (listener.accept(clients[clientCounter]) == sf::Socket::Status::Done) {
            std::cout << "New client connected: " 
                      << clients[clientCounter].getRemoteAddress() << std::endl;
            clientCounter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Main thread:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::thread serverListenerThread(&serverListener);

    while(true) {
        //std::cout << "Some message"; <----- when uncomment, the loop works?

        for (int i = 0; i < clientCounter; i++) {

            std::string message = "";
            packet >> message;

            if (clients[i].receive(packet) == sf::Socket::Status::Done) {

                message += std::to_string(i);
                std::cout << message << std::endl;
            }
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe your logic is incorrect on the accept test.  accept() blocks until a client connects.  sf::Socket::Status::Done would be an indication that your listener or client connect had closed already. you should change that `==` to a `!=` `if (listener.accept(clients[clientCounter]) != sf::Socket::Status::Done) {`  as shown in the tcp example here - https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/network-socket.php

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger? Where does the second thread get stuck? Do the `listen` or `accept` calls return the expected status codes>

Comment: FWIW, there is no guarantee that updates to the value of `clientCounter` in one thread will be seen in another. Change its type to `std::atomic<unsigned int>`.

Comment: Have you tried "nc localhost 1337" ?

Comment: Off-topic: If you want to prevent [exceptional programme exit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) caused by your thread object [running out of scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread), you should either join or detach the thread; joining, though requires additional synchronisation to make your thread function leave its while loop.

Comment: I understand your ideas, but think about the problem that this isnt working:
```c++
    while(true) {
        //std::cout << "Some message";
    }
```
, but this is:
```c++
    while(true) {
        std::cout << "Some message";      //<-------- the cout is triggering the loop??
    }
```

Comment: @Melwin The practical (ie implementation-specific) reason your loop doesn't work is the main thread only checks the value of `clientCounter` once. This is because you have provided no synchronization mechanism leading to the main thread believing its value cannot possibly change. When you print to `cout` the compiler presumably can't be sure whether the global variable has been modified as a side effect of the call and so it is forced to reevaluate it.

Comment: @Melwin You don't necessarily have to understand the reasoning behind this to avoid broken code, though. The C++ standard says accessing the same variable across threads without synchronization mechanisms is undefined behavior, ie anything at all can happen. Any code that causes undefined behavior is effectively broken even if it happens to work on some occasions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think for a moment about what the first thread sees. Since you have no syncronisation between the two threads, the compiler assumes they don't communicate and so the value of `clientCounter` will never change while the inner for loop is being executed. Thus the loop will always see `clientCounter=0` and so the loop doesn't run.

```
unsigned int clientCounter = 0;

int main()
{
    std::thread serverListenerThread(&serverListener);

    while(true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < clientCounter; i++) {
            // Never executed, since clientCounter = 0
        }
    }
}
```

You should make `clientCounter` an `std::atomic<unsigned int>`. This lets the compiler know to synchronise the variable between threads. In general, anything that you share between threads should either be atomic or should be protected by locking a mutex.

Adding a sleep *may* help but only by pure luck; there is absolutely no reason why it should continue to work.  In particular, there is no requirement to load the value of `clientCounter` from memory between while loop iterations, since the compiler 'knows' it is never written to in the main thread. Thus, reloading it would be redundant.